# Is there a way to modify the Windows 8.1 right-click start menu?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, start-menu

Is there a way to modify the Windows 8.1/Server 2012R2 `Win+X` context menu?

[image]

All my research eventually leads to this tool:

> [Win+X Menu Editor for Windows 8](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30)

However I'd rather not use this because I will eventually need to script my changes for multiple machines.

I know I could install that WinAero thing and use SysInternals ProcMon to monitor any registry and file changes it makes. However if anyone knows how to do this it'd be one less friction point in my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

There are folders with shortcuts in C:\Users\duncan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX, where you replace duncan with your username. The shortcuts must be hashed, however. Here is a tutorial for editing it without the editor: http://withinwindows.com/2012/04/04/windows-8-secrets-the-winx-menu-and-its-hashing-algorithm/
Note it has a program to hash the links for you. Then you can copy those links and they will still work on other computers.

Comment: Nice find. But I think something has changed in Windows 8.1/2012R2 since that tool was written. It sadly no longer works. Bloody Microsoft :)

Comment: LOL I'm using Privoxy with the "fun" filter activated, so here's what I saw: "It sadly no longer works. Bloody MicroSuck :) –  Kev"

Comment: @Kev You could also try setting up the shortcuts on one machine with the software you provided a link to, and then copying the shortcuts to your other machines. I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Turns out that the WinAero tool is an unobfuscated .NET app which contains, effectively, a port of the hashlnk tool (yay for .NET Reflector). With a wee bit of effort I'm sure I can knock up my own C# console app to do the right thing.

Comment: Marking as accepted because in a round about way it got me a solution.